# Recycler view not showing anything with SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have the following `NestedScrollView` with me which is working fine till now :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Now, I want to add `SwipeRefreshLayout` to it. So, I modified the view to :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

But as soon as I add this, the recycler view doesn't show anything (The screen is totally empty). Even in the xml preview, it shows nothing. I think I am making a silly mistake here, but not able to figure it out from the last 3 hours. Tried permuting between different height and width parameters but no luck.

Please help.

Comment: The swipeRefresh should be the root to avoid this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `NestedScrollView` as the parent of the recyclerView. NestedScrollView was never designed for the recyclerView